# Altair - Use the same axis for binned data and vertical annotation lines

Tags: python, pandas, graph, altair, vega-lite

I have a data source that I'm trying to bin and build a histogram out of. (Note that the data below is just as an example of the post-processed bin data).

My goal is to draw vertical lines to annotate different parts of the axis.

I got relatively close following other **StackOverflow** answers but the problem is that the axis for the vertical lines is separate from the axis for the binned data. My guess is that this is because the `x values` for the vertical lines are quantitative while the binned data is categorial.

Is there any way to have the vertical lines align with the `x-axis` on the bottom?

```python
data_bar = pd.DataFrame({
'bin': [0.78,0.82,0.88,0.92,0.98,1.02,1.08,1.12,1.18,1.23,1.27,1.32,1.38],
'freq': [0,3,18,95,279,416,660,411,263,200,53,22,0]
})
data_bar['bin'] = data_bar['bin'].astype('category')

data_lines = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': [0.8, 0.88, 1.001, 1.38],
    'title': ['no_match', 'match', 'no_match', 'match']     
})

bar = alt.Chart(data_bar).mark_bar().encode(x='bin', y='freq')
  
vertlines = alt.Chart(data_lines).mark_rule(
    color='black',
    strokeWidth=2
).encode(x='value')

text = alt.Chart(data_lines).mark_text(
    align='left', dx=5, dy=-5
).encode(
    x='value', text='title')


alt.layer(bar + vertlines + text).properties(width=500)
```

For reference, [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4Igxg9gdgZglgcxALlANzgUwO4tJKAFzigFcJSBnAdTgBNCALFAFgAY2AacaYsiygAlMiRoRQBmDgF9p3ADYBDAJ6YATigDaoJao3JtIOosKK8IKIoC2mFEZOKAtGwCMANgCsAThiK2EgA4AJhgvNi8AljdQlhcYOgB2L0wgjzoXMzkQK0U1AGs7ACNckG5MKEg6EiRUEAAPc0JlAAdbZAsIKxJFeVKQeEx5OiKSECzlRpa2kABHUkUiOFNiNFtuAaG7GDVMGbHZTlBjU3NLGztjpzYWRTcWBKC4yOSgtjcweMUgujYwRQSwC4PAl-mNuDl8pNWnY1KR5GsePIIPoQIUlGACtxKIQ1BA8phaAxmMggllypVquYGrUmtD2nMFsRlnBVn0NsN2mgeqRbLI5EcHKdrNNLs4bncHk8WC83h9jN9fv9AcDQVkIQUaVM7IRMHVxNweogoHZ4TB9UZqR5uHQJshHB4yRUIFUoDVQDq9VDplBOt1eussJt2kz4WD6l67AzFszWQHBhyQFz5Dz9tIALrp7jYehMFAeDjcAAklDAjEwOTsYkIzUoyAA9HXVghFAA6BBLRikQotuAQOslss5RuYZuOeRLTCNlgtgItlwtgBWlGgfUulEwhEo5lFrk8Pj8gRCYQiURicUSLzSGS0oEKo2QbBbCQC6x2ewf-NR98fwVfu0kn53saD4zi+-RvigLgBIB34tl4QR-u+XgOocX7AY+ESISgQRJDBwHzmwCHgf+yCxG4eGQS2bBgdsJFuG4bAUcg84uERtHvrELhMSxNEQSSbgSNxLZBBIWEkjIqFAZROFiR4gmSfe84SGxfFBKSCn4S2gRiYxabWg4Yq3PcjwwM8KSyp8Cp-ACQIggkN6JtybQ-twIbehAAD6OSEKWYLoE5KA-mBbl2N5vmfkmKbMVRriuUsobtD6XkmOFqGRW0SnBfF0xhcw6ayEAA) is the graph in a vega editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to plot your binned data on a quantitative axis, which you can do by setting `bin='binned'` and adding an `x2` encoding to specify the upper limit of each bin. Here are the required modifications to the data frame and the bar chart; the rest can stay the same:

```python
data_bar = pd.DataFrame({
'bin': [0.78,0.82,0.88,0.92,0.98,1.02,1.08,1.12,1.18,1.23,1.27,1.32,1.38],
'freq': [0,3,18,95,279,416,660,411,263,200,53,22,0]
})
data_bar['bin_max'] = data_bar['bin'].shift(-1).fillna(data_bar['bin'].max() + 0.05)

# Note: don't convert data['bin'] to category

bar = alt.Chart(data_bar).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('bin', bin='binned'),
    x2='bin_max',
    y='freq')
```

Here is the resulting chart:
[image]